# "Lost connection to MySQL server" when trying to connect to remote MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am using Zend Framework to develop my application and I try to connect to a remote MySQL database in my LAN.

The database connection settings in Zend is as follows:

```
[GENERAL]
db.adapter     = PDO_MYSQL
db.params.host = 192.168.1.2
db.params.port = 3306
```

[LIVE:GENERAL]
db.params.username = root
db.params.password = ********
db.params.dbname   = djudd

[DEVELOPMENT:GENERAL]
db.params.username = root
db.params.password = ********
db.params.dbname   = stellarengine

I got the following error:

> > > `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111' in /usr/share/php/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129 Stack trace: #0 /usr/share/php/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(129): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=192....', 'root', 'password', Array) #1 /usr/share/php/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #2 /usr/share/php/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(448): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #3 /usr/share/php/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE`bny_c...', Array) #4 /usr/share/php/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(156): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `bny_c...') #5 /usr/share/php/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(823): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->describeTable('bny_core_module...', NULL) #6 /usr/share/php/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(866): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupMetadata() #7 /usr/share/php/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract. in /usr/share/php/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 144`

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: I hope that you are not actually using `root` as your database credentials...  That could be quite dangerous if there's any type of attack (filesystem or sql injection)...

Comment: might try using the remote host IP (or Name) instead of the local default gateway IP of 192.168.1.2

Comment: Maybe this is not related with zend framework, you need to test just with a simple mysql_connect() function. Probably the error is with your mysql server or network configuration.

Answer (score 7):

Last time I had this type of error, I had to change my host from: **127.0.0.1** to '**localhost**' and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

This might help: [MySQL Forum: 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,151255,151255)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, to solve it I changed the remote port in the tunnel configuration from `'localhost:3306' to '127.0.0.1:3306'.`

In the target machine, localhost was resolving to ::1 but MariaDB was not listening IPv6 requests...

Answer (score 0):

This error means you're connecting to the wrong server or the firewall blocked it or the server isn't running.

You'll need to contact the server administrator to confirm the correct details.

With most servers you'll use `127.0.0.1` but some use `localhost` while others (like media temple) will need a full domain name - for example `internal-db.s421234.gridserver.com`