# Mysql exception after moving drupal site PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013]

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I just moved my drupal site to another domain/host

I moved the DB and now all my sites. But when I visit the website (juniorsteps.be), I get the following exception:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111 in lock_may_be_available() (line 165 of /home/sites/webhosting/juniorsteps/juniorsteps/www/includes/lock.inc).

I googled it but I still don't find a solution.

Hope someone can help.

UPDATE

As asked the code from line . It's the first line of the following function:

```
function lock_may_be_available($name) {
  $lock = db_query('SELECT expire, value FROM {semaphore} WHERE name = :name', array(':name' => $name))->fetchAssoc();
  if (!$lock) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  $expire = (float) $lock['expire'];
  $now = microtime(TRUE);
  if ($now > $expire) {
    // We check two conditions to prevent a race condition where another
    // request acquired the lock and set a new expire time. We add a small
    // number to $expire to avoid errors with float to string conversion.
    return (bool) db_delete('semaphore')
      ->condition('name', $name)
      ->condition('value', $lock['value'])
      ->condition('expire', 0.0001 + $expire, '<=')
      ->execute();
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

But to be honest I do not think the mistake is in my code since it works perfectly on my development server.

Comment: Voted to close, your question cannot be answered in its current form, we need way more detail than that. The code around line 165 of `/home/sites/webhosting/juniorsteps/juniorsteps/www/includes/lock.inc` would be a good start.

Comment: I added the code, but I don't think it's the code since the site works on my development server and now that I moved it, I get the error. :s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your settings.php

```
  $databases = array (

  'default' => 

   array (

    'default' =>

    array (

      'database' => '333333',

      'username' => '333333',

      'password' => '3333333',

      'host' => '122.124.12.09', // check host -> maybe not localhost

      'port' => '3304',  // check port!

      'driver' => 'mysql',

      'prefix' => '',

      ),

    ),

   );
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The development version of the site was setup for use with the Acquia development environment. The `settings.php` was incorrect. Delete all the Acquia specific information from the bottom lines of the `sites/default/settings.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help you:
["Lost connection to MySQL server" when trying to connect to remote MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499968/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-when-trying-to-connect-to-remote-mysql-server/4500264#4500264)

And readup on the MySQL documentation on error 2013: `server has gone away`
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html