# Magento Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 113

Tags: magento

I have copy the magento website from one server to another and done all the necessary changes and now when i opened my new site the following error is coming

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1237612538

It is showing the numbers of errors first is

```
a:4:{i:0;s:115:
"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 113"
;i:1;s:2374:"
#0 /home/content/32/9503032/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
```

Comment: check in var/report folder for this error number, what error you have get?

Comment: yes,but first check in error report folder what error comes?

Comment: It is showing the numbers of errors first is

a:4:{i:0;s:115:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 113";i:1;s:2374:"#0 /home/content/32/9503032/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()

Comment: This looks to be an issue between you and your web host. It's possible you are supposed to be connecting to your db with different parameters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499968/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-when-trying-to-connect-to-remote-mysql-server this may be useful to you

Comment: change lib/Zend/Cache/Checkout/File.php, look for an array called $_options, the first line change null to tmp/. Create magento/tmp/. Copy error/local.xml.sample to error/local/local.xml. This should give you the actual error you're getting. If you can provide the error I'm sure someone can get you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

Are you sure changed db credentials correct in xml file?

1 .Recheck db credentials with username and password correct or not?

1. File permisions
2. compilation mode enable/disable
3. clear cache
4. clear sesion

try it

Answer (score 0):

if you want to more detail in error, you can change a little bit step as follows
go to Magento Folder

1. Magento Folder
2. errors
3. local.xml.sample to local.xml
4. Refresh Page. You will see more detail errors.