# Symfony : how to set SSL parameters in Doctrine DBAL configuration (YAML)?

Tags: symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm, yaml, dbal

I'd like to add my SSL cert and key files to Doctrine DBAL configuration but I don't see how to achieve that.

In PHP, I just have to write something like :

```
$databaseHandler = new \PDO(
    'mysql:host=my_host;dbname=my_db',
    'username',
    'password',
    array(
        \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY   => '.../client-key.pem',
        \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT  => '.../client-cert.pem',
        \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA    => '.../ca-cert.pem'
    )
);
```

I understand there is a [Custom Driver Option](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#custom-driver-options) `driverOptions`, and I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039947/symfony2-doctrine-connect-to-database-via-ssl) but I'm not sure about how to translate that into YAML.

I have the feeling I should write something close to :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        driverOptions:
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA: '.../client-key.pem'
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT: '.../client-cert.pem'
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA: '.../ca-cert.pem'
```

But double colons won't really please YAML...

Comment: Just use the actual values of the constants.  php -r "echo PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA;" yields 1009 so replace PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA with 1009.  Bit of a hack perhaps but the numbers won't change.

Comment: Oh you learn me something : each property of each PHP class and its extensions has a unique id ?

Comment: All constants have a value.  And while it's possible that the value may change with newer versions of PHP it's very rare.

Comment: Ok :) Thank you very much ! Meanwhile somebody may know a "cleaner" way, I will do like that.

Comment: its bad idea to use constant values instead of constant names. Right now php -r "echo PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA;" shows 1012 in php 5.5.9

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since [Symfony 3.2](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-php-constants-in-yaml-files) this became a lot easier:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        <other configs>
        options:
            !php/const:PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA: %ca_cert%
            !php/const:PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY: %private_key%
            !php/const:PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT: %public_cert%
```

Answer (score 8):

I found a much easier way than the rest.
Make the following settings in `app/config/config.yml`:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # Options for SSL connection
        options:
            MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA : %ca_cert%
            MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY : %private_key%
            MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT : %public_cert%
```

Then in your `app/config/parameters.yml` file:

```
parameters:
    ...
    # SSL Info
    private_key: /etc/my.cnf.d/certs/client-key.pem
    public_cert: /etc/my.cnf.d/certs/client-cert.pem
    ca_cert: /etc/my.cnf.d/certs/ca-cert.pem
```

I tested this on Symfony3 and this works great. The paths above may be different, in particular the certs may be different depending on your distro and how you set it up.

Comment: And probably both Andrew Zhilin and @Cerad will be happy because there is no need to specify constant values!

Comment: Tested on Symfony 3.2 with PHP 5.6.20 and it does not work for me. As you specify strings, and as PDO expects associated numbers to PDO constants, it can't work. I prefer @Samuel Scheiderich solution. Tested and approved.

Comment: Hi @Delphine. I had originally tried/used Samuel's (and also Valentas) solution, but then I came up with my own. I suspect you may have had a problem with your yaml file or something else, because I believe my solution should work - you may want to double-check. Your statement about 'can't work' does not seem correct.

Comment: I understand your point of view but my PDO string receives only "MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA" and not a conversion to associated number. Maybe we can configure something in php.in or mycf.ini to accept both.. I said that it does not work for me and I explain that, for me, PDO received string and not number equivalent. Maybe I was not so clear..

Comment: It doesn't work: 1) Use `tcpdump`, you'll see the connection isn't encrypted. 2) Try: `SHOW STATUS WHERE Variable_name = 'Ssl_cipher'`, you'll see the variable is empty.

Comment: Hi there @NielasAran. My configuration is basically cut and paste from a working Production system. The names of the pem files are obfuscated. If it's not working for you, it's possible you didn't create the SSL correctly. That's a lot of work - believe me, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: My configuration is correct: It works if I use Robert's solution. I checked with `tcpdump` and `Ssl_cipher`. The fact you're able to connect doesn't mean the connection is encrypted. Another way to check is to reject non-encrypted connection with `require_secure_transport` or with `REQUIRE SSL`. So, 4 ways to check so far.

Answer (score 4):

Now in 2020, with Symfony > 4.2, the solution is :

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # Options for SSL connection
        options:
            !php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA : %ca_cert%
            !php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY : %private_key%
            !php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT : %public_cert%
```

Source : [symfony.com/doc/4.2/service_container/parameters.html](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/service_container/parameters.html)

Tested with Symfony 5.1.8

Answer (score 3):

Symfony configuration via yaml (and possibly xml), doesn't allow the keys to be dynamically set, which means you can't use the constants. To get around this, you can create an extra PHP config file that just handles making a key out of the constants.

The solution in a Gist is here: https://gist.github.com/samsch/d5243de3924a8ad10df2

The two major features that this utilizes are that a PHP config file can use any string value for the key, including variables, constants; and that you can use parameters as values for other parameters (something I didn't know until I tried it recently.)

So, you add the PHP config file in config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: pdo-constants.php }
```

pdo-constants.php is this:

```
<?php
$container->setParameter("pdo_options", [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => "%pdo_ca_file%",
]);
```

Add any other constants you need as well.

Then in parameters.yml, you just need the values for your constants:

```
parameters:
#...
    pdo_ca_file: /pathtocerts/certs/mysql-ca.pem
```

Now, I'm guessing that working with another DB system which uses PDO constants would be similar, but I've only used this MySQL.

Comment: I was stuck with Doc2, PHP 5.6.22 and Symfony 2 ! It didn't recognize "1010" as a key and parsed it like certificate.. Obviously, it tells that it was a "bad certificate" (Oh ? Normal, it's a key..) ! If your solution works, you really will save my day !

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `PDO` constats, You shoul use their values in `options`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
                options:
                    1010 : %private_key% 
                    1011 : %public_cert% 
                    1012 : %ca_cert%
```

Comment: Not sure where you got "1012", but PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA is 1009.

Comment: its bad idea to use constant values instead of constant names. Right now php -r "echo PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA;" shows 1012 in php 5.5.9. And it was 1009 some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

[An alternative approach](https://www.colinodell.com/blog/202002/zeroconfiguration-ssl-ca-root-bundles-doctrine-dbal-symfony) would be installing [`composer/ca-bundle`](https://github.com/composer/ca-bundle) to help find the path to the CA root bundle and use a [custom compiler pass](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html) to automagically register that path with Doctrine:

```php
<?php

namespace App\DepenedencyInjection\Compiler;

use Composer\CaBundle\CaBundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

/**
 * Registers a CA root bundle with the PDO MySQL driver used by Doctrine DBAL
 *
 * This allows Doctrine to connect to MySQL instances that force SSL encryption, such as Azure's.
 */
final class RegisterCABundleWithPDOMysqlDriverPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $caPathOrFile = CaBundle::getSystemCaRootBundlePath();

        foreach ($container->getParameter('doctrine.connections') ?? [] as $connectionName) {
            $definition = $container->getDefinition($connectionName);
            $options = $definition->getArgument(0) ?? [];
            $options['driverOptions'][\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA] = $caPathOrFile;
            $definition->setArgument(0, $options);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using PHP 5.6.40 on docker and have been debugging why my local would not connect via ssl. For some weird reason it wants const 1009 instead of 1012. Dropping this answer here in case anyone stumbles upon it on the future.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                options:
                    1001: true
                    1009: %ssl_cert_path%
```